# External services signin link asp core

Tags: linux, asp.net-core, oauth

I use external auth for my asp core application. On localhost everything works perfectly but when I try to deploy the project on ubuntu server an issue appears.
My site works on 5001 port in the linux server and when I call Challenge method to redirect user to signin page it returns `http://localhost:5001/signin-google`
and in doesn't work because google can't return result to unaccessible from internet localhost (I can call from my computer the project when it's on localhost on my computer but not when it's on localhost on the server). I tried to define auth url explicitly like this: `options.CallbackPath = "https://myproject.com/signin-google";` but options.CallbackPath requires value that starts with '/'. So what can I do?

**Updated**

Tried to set request cookies myself like this:

```
.AddGoogle(options =>
                {
                    options.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"];
                    options.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"];
                    options.Events = new OAuthEvents
                    {
                        OnRedirectToAuthorizationEndpoint = async context =>
                        {
                            context.Request.Headers.Remove("Scheme");
                            context.Request.Headers.Add("Scheme", "https");
                            context.Request.Headers.Remove("Host");
                            context.Request.Headers.Add("Host", "myhost.com");
                        }
                    };
                    options.CallbackPath = "/signin-google";
```

but after Challenge there was no redirect to google auth page

Comment: There is an issue just like mine: https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/1036 But I can't understand how to use HttpOverrides to replace default request headers :(

Answer (score 0):

I've realized. I just had to configure nginx like this:

```
 server {
                listen 80;
                server_name example.com;
                location / {
                        proxy_pass http://localhost:5001;
                        proxy_http_version 1.1;
                        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto http;
                        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
                        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Host $remote_addr;
                        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                        proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
                        proxy_set_header Host $host;
                        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                }
```

and added

```
app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
            {
                ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
            });
```

That's all